# Volume of a cube with integration.

Tags: integration, proof-verification

Say we wanted to derive the formula for the volume of a cube *with integration*. Each "slice" of the cube has area $x^2$, with "width" $dx$. Integrate from $0$ to $x$, and I believe you would get the following:

$$\int_0^x x^2dx$$

And this equals $\frac 13x^3$, however the volume of a cube is given by $x^3$!

What is wrong with this process?

Comment: variable confusion - if $x$ is the length of a side of the cube, then you want to integrate with respect to another variable, say $dt$, as you want $x$ to be a constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that with $\int_0^x x^2dx$ you are actually calculating the volume of a kind of inverted pyramid. As @Fermat suggested, you have to maintain the side fixed (through $a^2$), otherwise it changes as the third axis does.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be the side of the cube then $$V=\int_{0}^{a}a^2dx=a^2 x| _{0}^{a}=a^3$$